# Add item to source control without mapping

Tags: version-control, tfs

I have a folder in source control that is *not mapped* and I want to add a subfolder that is also *not mapped*.

It seems that I first have to create a mapping, then check in the subfolder and then remove the mapping. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure is a good idea to mix in the same folder files that are stored in TFS and files that should not be stored. Because is a classic when you change/move to another PC you forgot those files. If they are not important I suggest to keep them in another place.

Anyway, if you want you can modifiy *.vbproj/*.csproj files and manually add your entries. They will not be added to Source Control automatically when you reload the project.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Temp\file1.txt" />
    <None Include="Temp\Nested\file2.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Interesting. I was just surprised that it is not possible to create folders in tfs directly. In the end removing the mapping and creating a new one is ok.